# What exactly does the {} argument reference do?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am a new with progress-4gl (OpenEdge) and I have run into some code that for the life of my I can't understand exactly what it does. Below is an example of the code I am trying to dissect and all the material I have found on the situation.

I realize that my answer is in the material however I can't really understand it as well as I want to. Hopefully someone with a bit more knowledge than me can help me. Thanks for anyone who has spent on this:

```
Function functionName RETURNS CHAR ( integerName AS INT ) {1}:
```

This function is stored in an include file and is being called by a different procedure in the following way:

```
charName = GetCommSecType ( intName )
```

What I don't completely understand is why the {1} is there and what exactly is it doing. If I don't put the {1} everything seems to work the same. I have looked in the help file pasted its information below:

> { } Argument reference:
>   References the value of an argument that a procedure passes to a called external procedure file or to an include file.
>   ABL converts each argument to a character format. This conversion removes the surrounding double-quotes if the parameter was specified as a character string constant in the RUN statement or include file reference.
>   When one procedure is called from another and arguments are used, ABL recompiles the called procedure, substituting the arguments that the calling procedure passes, and then runs the called procedure.

I believe the purpose of this is to allow the include files function to be run on a command line RUN command. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{} is something called a preprocessor meaning that it only affects the outcome of your program during compile time, not run time.

Generally you would include a .i file, not run it but this kind of syntax could be used both for running and including files.

In this perticular case it means that the compiler will insert something where {1} is written. {1} signifies the first argument inserted. You can name arguments as well (see the link below).

A simple include of a file like this:

```
{filename.i}
```

In this case it's not very easy to guess whats inserted but basically if you do an include like this:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE c AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
c = "ABC".
{c:\temp\includetest.i c}
```

The compiler will insert ABC where {1} is written in your include file. That would make no sense in this example of course. And I don't now of anything that really can be written between the parameters and the colon.

Let's say your the filname.i file simply contains.

```
DISPLAY {1}.
```

Doing the include like above would then make the compiler replace {1} with "ABC" and thus making the statement look like this:

```
DISPLAY c.
```

Running this would display the value of c - "ABC".

You would have to provide the code running or including your file for better understanding of this!

Pages 22 and forward in [this document](http://documentation.progress.com/output/OpenEdge113/pdfs/dvref/dvref.pdf?_ga=1.204928979.237806638.1386954836) describes this deeper.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the referenced document, that is the same document I went through before posting. My one question to your explanation is the following: the function in the  include file function has a parameter and a {1}. So when my procedure calls the function in the include file it passes in an Integer. So then does the Interger get passed twice?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with tha calling of the function. It effects the include or the run of the file.

Comment: The number inside the {} has nothing to do with parameters to the functions nor is used as an integer, it relates to the position of the parameter passed when the include is used.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up, I think I understand now. Just need to have more practice with pre-processor coding.